# fmemopen is changing the mapped file Structure

Tags: c

I am trying to map a char* of an executable file into memory using the fmemopen function that should return a FILE * to be able to use it(without writing it to the hard drive at all). The issue that the fmemopen function change the file so that when I write the file from the FILE* it has a different format unrecognized.

```
    FILE * stream;
stream = fmemopen(value, strlen(value), "rb");                                                                                                FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("testing.exe", "w");
    fwrite(stream, leng, 1, fp);
```

Where value is a (char*) and leng is the char * length.

Any advice would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Given your block of code we can only hazard a bad guess as to why the resulting executable is not correct. You don't seem to be using consistent variables (`fp3` vs `fp`, what is `leng`?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rereading your code, I have some more observations:

1. It is apparent you are not passing the correct parameters to `fwrite`. The first parameter is a pointer to a buffer of memory, not another `FILE*`. In this case you're copying bizarre memory into the new executable, which is why it cannot be executed.

   If you have a block of memory you would like to copy to an executable, simply `fwrite` that block of memory:

   ```
   FILE* fp_out = fopen("testing.exe", "wb");
   /* ... */
   fwrite(value, sizeof(value), 1, fp_out);
   ```

   However, this assumes `value` is a full and complete executable image suitable for execution (you probably need a `chmod +x testing.exe`). I'm left to wonder, given an extension of `.exe`, if this binary image even contains a valid executable for your platform.
2. You do not want to use `strlen` when dealing with a supposed executable image, even if it is "stored" in a `char*`. Executables contain byte values of 0, which are the C-string delimiter character NUL (e.g. `'\0'`). This will cause `strlen` to fumble. You'll need to use `sizeof` or keep track of the size of the executable image.
3. It would be best to use `"wb"` in your call to `fopen` if you made the effort to use `"rb"` in your call to `fmemopen`. This way you do not receive newline translation on systems which do this ([Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx)). If you're on a platform which does not make this requirement, either remove the `b` from the calls or keep it. Whatever you choose, be consistent.

Comment: I think this is the real problem - the OP is writing data from the `FILE` struct that `fmemopen()` returns, not the array (`value`) which that `FILE` object references as its buffer...

Comment: Agreed, and the `strlen` will certainly not be correct if the executable image contains even a single zero-valued byte.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices. I agree about the strlen,"wb" (fixed both), but for the FILE * stream I am mainly doing it to be able to read and use it as a file that could be read by other part of the program without having a real file written on the hard drive (if I will keep reading and writing through the value then fmemopen is useless).

Comment: @Moh: a `void*` buffer and an `off_t` byte offset are sufficient to make a raw buffer roughly identical to using the file I/O routines. Otherwise, you'll need to use `fread` to get data from the stream retrieved by `fmemopen`, and then write that data to the other stream.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said fmemopen changed the way the file was, please note you selected "rb" as the mode. Which stands for read as binary. Try with just "r".

Edit[Thanks Scott]
Since you're writing to an executable, you would keep "rb", and you would then have to write with "wb".

Comment: If the OP is updating an executable, they probably would enjoy the behavior of `rb` on OS's which require the `b`.

Comment: I think you have the right idea in the wrong direction - instead of fopening the output as "w", they should probably do so as "wb", since the .exe *is* a binary file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices but I tried to both W and Wb but still getting the same results. I am using Linux OS on .exe files

Comment: @Moh: then most likely you have a problem in code you're not showing us. As it stands it is very hard to figure out what is wrong with your code.